# GL & GLSL: Bump Mapping: What's wrong with this textbook example?

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping

**Here's what the README says this example does:** "bump map on one polygon with a rotation light". Let me add: the polygon is a square, and the bump map on it should produce a raised-looking square within the original polygon square. The values for i and j (pixel iteration) in the second 'for' loop in main() are indicative of this inner square pattern.

**Problem**: When I run it, the display window comes up but it's blank white. 
Maybe you can try running it yourself: if it works, let's find differences in our setup; if it, doesn't please help find what's wrong with the code. The code   is here: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/. Click on "Code", then "CHAPTER07/". It's example 7.3. Also, below is the code for reference. Note: I added "#version 150" to fshader73.glsl to get rid of a version error at runtime.

**example3.cpp**:

```
/* sets up flat mesh */
/* sets up elapsed time parameter for use by shaders */

#include "Angel.h"

#define N 256

GLfloat normals[N][N][3];
GLuint         program;
GLuint        texMapLocation;
GLfloat tangent[3] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0};

typedef Angel::vec4  point4;
typedef Angel::vec4  color4;

point4 points[6];
vec2 tex_coord[6];
mat4 ctm, projection;

vec4 normal = point4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
color4 light_diffuse = color4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
color4 material_diffuse = color4(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
point4  light_position = point4(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 eye =  vec4(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0);
vec4 at = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);
vec4 up = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);



GLuint loc, loc2;
GLuint buffers[2];

GLuint normal_loc;
GLuint diffuse_product_loc;
GLuint light_position_loc;
GLuint ctm_loc, projection_loc;
GLuint tangent_loc;


/* standard OpenGL initialization */

vec4 product(vec4 a, vec4 b)
{
  return vec4(a[0]*b[0], a[1]*b[1], a[2]*b[2], a[3]*b[3]);
}
static void init()
{
    const float meshColor[]     = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f}; 

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, meshColor);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, N, N, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, normals);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

   loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
   glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, points);

   loc2 = glGetAttribLocation(program, "texcoord");
   glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc2);
   glVertexAttribPointer(loc2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, tex_coord);

   glGenBuffers(2, buffers);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   tangent_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "objTangent");
   glUniform3fv(tangent_loc, 3, tangent);

   normal_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "Normal");
   glUniform4fv(normal_loc, 4, normal);

   vec4 diffuse_product = product(light_diffuse, material_diffuse);
   diffuse_product_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "DiffuseProduct");
   glUniform4fv(diffuse_product_loc, 4, diffuse_product);

   light_position_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "LightPosition");
   glUniform4fv(light_position_loc, 4, light_position);

   ctm_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "ModelView");
   ctm = LookAt(eye, at , up);
   glUniformMatrix4fv(ctm_loc, 16, GL_TRUE, ctm);

   mat4 nm;
   GLfloat det;
   det = ctm[0][0]*ctm[1][1]*ctm[2][2]+ctm[0][1]*ctm[1][2]*ctm[2][1]
     -ctm[2][0]*ctm[1][1]*ctm[0][2]-ctm[1][0]*ctm[0][1]*ctm[2][2]-ctm[0][0]*ctm[1][2]*ctm[2][1];
   nm[0][0] = (ctm[1][1]*ctm[2][2]-ctm[1][2]*ctm[2][1])/det;
   nm[0][1] = -(ctm[0][1]*ctm[2][2]-ctm[0][2]*ctm[2][1])/det;
   nm[0][2] = (ctm[0][1]*ctm[2][0]-ctm[2][1]*ctm[2][2])/det;
   nm[1][0] = -(ctm[0][1]*ctm[2][2]-ctm[0][2]*ctm[2][1])/det;
   nm[1][1] = (ctm[0][0]*ctm[2][2]-ctm[0][2]*ctm[2][0])/det;
   nm[1][2] = -(ctm[0][0]*ctm[2][1]-ctm[2][0]*ctm[0][1])/det;
   nm[2][0] = (ctm[0][1]*ctm[1][2]-ctm[1][1]*ctm[0][2])/det;
   nm[2][1] = -(ctm[0][0]*ctm[1][2]-ctm[0][2]*ctm[1][0])/det;
   nm[2][2] = (ctm[0][0]*ctm[1][1]-ctm[1][0]*ctm[0][1])/det;

    GLuint nm_loc;
    nm_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "NormalMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(nm_loc, 16, GL_TRUE, nm);

    projection_loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "Projection");
    projection = Ortho(-0.75,0.75,-0.75,0.75,-5.5,5.5);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_loc, 16, GL_TRUE, projection);

    texMapLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texMap");

}

    /* set up uniform parameter */

void mesh()
{
      point4 vertices[4] = {point4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), point4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
         point4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), point4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)};

       points[0] = vertices[0];
       tex_coord[0] = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
       points[1] = vertices[1];
       tex_coord[1] = vec2(1.0, 0.0);
       points[2] = vertices[2];
       tex_coord[2] = vec2(1.0, 1.0);
       points[3] = vertices[2];
       tex_coord[3] = vec2(1.0, 1.0);
       points[4] = vertices[3];
       tex_coord[4] = vec2(0.0, 1.0);
       points[5] = vertices[0];
       tex_coord[5] = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
}

static void draw()
{

    glUniform1i(texMapLocation, 0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mesh(); 

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

static void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 27:
    case 'Q':
    case 'q':
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

void idle()
{
   int t;
   t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
   light_position[0] = 5.5*sin(0.001*t);
   light_position[2] = 5.5*cos(0.001*t);
   glUniform4fv(light_position_loc, 4, light_position);
   glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i,j, k;
    float d;

    float data[N+1][N+1];
    for(i=0;i<N+1;i++) for(j=0;j<N+1;j++) data[i][j]=0.0;
    for(i=N/4; i< 3*N/4; i++) for(j=N/4;j<3*N/4;j++) data[i][j] = 1.0;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++) for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
       normals[i][j][0] = data[i][j]-data[i+1][j];
       normals[i][j][2] = data[i][j]-data[i][j+1];
       normals[i][j][1]= 1.0;
    }


    for(i=0;i<N;i++) for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
       d = 0.0;
       for(k=0;k<3;k++) d+=normals[i][j][k]*normals[i][j][k];
       d=sqrt(d);
       for(k=0;k<3;k++) normals[i][j][k]= 0.5*normals[i][j][k]/d+0.5;
    }

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 1024);

    glutInitContextVersion( 3, 2 );
    glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );

    glutCreateWindow("Simple GLSL example");
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glewInit();

    program = InitShader("vshader73.glsl", "fshader73.glsl");
    init();


    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

**vshader73.glsl**:

```
/* bump map vertex shader */

#version 150

out vec3 L; /* light vector in texture-space coordinates */
out vec3 V; /* view vector in texture-space coordinates */

in vec2 texcoord;
in vec4 vPosition;

uniform vec4 Normal;
uniform vec4 LightPosition;
uniform mat4 ModelView;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 NormalMatrix;
uniform vec3 objTangent; /* tangent vector in object coordinates */

out vec2 st;

void main()
{
    mat3 NM3;

    NM3[0][0] = NormalMatrix[0][0];
    NM3[0][1] = NormalMatrix[0][1];
    NM3[0][2] = NormalMatrix[0][2];
    NM3[1][0] = NormalMatrix[1][0];
    NM3[1][1] = NormalMatrix[1][1];
    NM3[1][2] = NormalMatrix[1][2];
    NM3[2][0] = NormalMatrix[2][0];
    NM3[2][1] = NormalMatrix[2][1];
    NM3[2][2] = NormalMatrix[2][2];

    gl_Position = Projection*ModelView*vPosition;


    st = texcoord;

    vec3 eyePosition = vec3(ModelView*vPosition);
    vec3 eyeLightPos = LightPosition.xyz;

   /* normal, tangent and binormal in eye coordinates */

    vec3 N = normalize(NM3*Normal.xyz);
    vec3 T  = normalize(NM3*objTangent);
    vec3 B = cross(N, T);

    /* light vector in texture space */

    L.x = dot(T, eyeLightPos-eyePosition);
    L.y = dot(B, eyeLightPos-eyePosition);
    L.z = dot(N, eyeLightPos-eyePosition);

    L = normalize(L);

    /* view vector in texture space */

    V.x = dot(T, -eyePosition);
    V.y = dot(B, -eyePosition);
    V.z = dot(N, -eyePosition);

    V = normalize(V);
}
```

**fshader73.glsl**:

```
#version 150

in vec3 L;
in vec3 V;
uniform sampler2D texMap;
in vec2 st;
uniform vec4 DiffuseProduct;

out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{

   vec4 N = texture2D(texMap, st);
   vec3 NN =  normalize(2.0*N.xyz-1.0);
   vec3 LL = normalize(L);
   float Kd = max(dot(NN.xyz, LL), 0.0);
   fColor = Kd*DiffuseProduct;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Following Brett's comment, I replaced `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)` with the below -- still getting a blank white window:

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
...
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Comment: You can't use the texture binding `(0)`, it's reserved for the 'default' texture - see: `glGenTextures`.

Comment: Ah so perhaps there is no texture to be bound, because the default texture has not been set? I'm going to ditch the 0 and use `glGenTextures` to put my own texture into the binding. Any idea how the author intended this example to work?

Comment: In the meantime, please anyone, I'm not really convinced that glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0) is incorrect. An explanation of what the default texture is in this case, why it is incorrect, and the proper way to use "default texture" would help.

Comment: I'm now pretty sure `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)` is not the problem. See my edit. Anything else? Anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex my friend you were close! Basically, EVERY `glUniform...` call in there, not just the `glUniformMatrix...` ones, need `1` as their second argument.

Answer (score 1):

My comment went just over the limit of characters, so hopefully this is worth an answer.

The only thing I can see that might be a problem are your `glUniformMatrix4fv` calls. The second parameter, according to the [OpenGl 4 language reference](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glUniform.xml) describes it as the number of matrices to change. The 3.2 core reference pages aren't linked on their site, so I couldn't look it up for that particular context. So for `glUniformMatrix4fv(projection_loc, 16, GL_TRUE, projection);` it intends to find sixteen matrices in an array called "Projection", yet you only defined `uniform mat4 Projection;`. This may or may not be a part of your problem, and it's possible I'm not even correct, especially if this is a known tutorial that other people have compiled/used.

Also, glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) isn't necessary ([or even usable, i think?](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/171415-OpenGL-3-X-glEnable%28GL_TEXTURE_2D%29-GL_INVALID_ENUM)) with an OpenGL context of version 3.2 core, which was set up here:

```
glutInitContextVersion( 3, 2 );
glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
```

If the compiler isn't giving you any errors, trying adding `glGetError()` after lines which you think may be problematic. The return value maps to an enum value in the header file for OpenGL ([glcorearb.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/#headers) will list them), and i think the documentation lists them as well.

Other than that, you may just want to check that the "normals" 3-dimensional array is laid out in memory the way you expect it to be, as I've never tried manually constructing an array to be used as a texture myself (though images are basically strings of byte data anyways, so I don't see how it's a problem in this case).

Hopefully this helped you, or at least pointed you in the right direction. Good luck.

**Edit #1**: I realized my comment about shader checking wasn't very complete, as I failed to mention some API calls. Here's an example of it though:

```
      char * dataBuffer;
      struct _stat fileStat;
      long fLen;
      FILE * vSh;
      FILE * fSh;
      int desc;

      GLint status;
      GLint logLength;

      GLuint vShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
      //errort = glGetError();
      GLuint fShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
      GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
      /*__________________________________________________*/

      vSh = fopen("vShader.vSh", "r");
      desc = _fileno(vSh);
      _fstat(desc, &fileStat);

      fLen = fileStat.st_size;

      dataBuffer = (char *) calloc((fLen + 1), sizeof(char));
      if (dataBuffer == NULL)
      {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Malloc failure: VS", "Create Program", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            return 1;
      }


      if(feof(vSh) == 0)
      {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Did not reach EoF for VS", "Create Program", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            return 2;
      }
      fclose(vSh);

      glShaderSource(vShader, 1, &dataBuffer, NULL);
      glCompileShader(vShader);

      //Error checking
      glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
      if (status == GL_FALSE)
      {
            glGetShaderiv(vShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
            char resultV[logLength+1];
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vShader, logLength, NULL, resultV);

            MessageBox(NULL, resultV, "Vertex Compile Error", MB_OK);
      }
      free(dataBuffer);
```

The way I get my shader isn't the real important part, so hopefully that doesn't confuse you. The part labelled `//Error checking` is the stuff I meant, when talking about checking your shader for errors.

Comment: Thanks for giving this thought. Good find for the matrix calls, it seems the author mistook the second the parameter for element count rather than matrix count. I thought this must be the issue, but I changed all of the 16's in these calls to 1's and still nothing! I also tried getting rid of the glEnable. Strange thing about error checking: I get error 1282 no matter where I check (even in working code), EXCEPT for a check that I put below glTexImage2D() in, where I get 1280 (GL_INVALID_ENUM?). I can't put much more time into this at the moment, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just looked at the reference pages, and apparently more than one error flag can be raised, but only one flag gets returned at a time per call. So you need to loop until you see  `GL_NO_ERROR`, to be sure there aren't other errors hiding around. If it is _always_ 1282, then I'm not sure what's going on... it's possibly that the flag values are OR'd together, so you're getting a combination of errors. On the other hand, it might be gibberish? I really don't know. I'll take a look at the code another time, perhaps. No time at the moment.

Comment: Also take a look at glGetShaderInfoLog and glGetProgramInfoLog from the reference pages. I use those to debug my shaders, and they work fairly well. I can edit my answer with an example if you'd like. Or does InitShader take care of that?